# In adiabatic condition, how can i find ground state through time evolution operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution, adiabatic

decompose the evolution operator into a sequence of steps using the Trotter-Suzuki formula

[image]

unitary operator is the evolution operator from 0 to $T $, $k$ is a large integer so that $τ = T /k$ is a small time segment, and before exponential term is time ordering operator. if inital and problem(final) hamiltonian is given by

[image]

and A(s) is path of time evolution. in here, we assume A(s) = t/T

if start ground state of an initial hamiltonian, is it possible to make unitary operator to find ground state of final hamiltonian in adiabatic condition.
and how i can find it?

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to enter mathematical 
expressions on Physics SE, as it is the site standard. Images of text or equations 
are very strongly discouraged.

Comment: ok, thanks. i will do